# VHDL audio sample volume control

Tags: audio, vhdl

I was searching a lot about this problem, but I cant find anything usefull... 
The problem is, Im making echo efect on FPGA chip.. I have everything prepared, like BRAM for delay, input, output with delay, but I can't find out, how to change volume of output which is coming back to input, to mix them together and send them again to BRAM..
Becouse when I just simply conect output to input, it makes a cycle of BRAM to infinite, but I need to change the volume of output, which is coming back to input, to half of its volume..
I read it can be achived by shifting sample to the right, but it makes a lot of noise over the sample..

Im using 16 bit samples

So I'm asking for ideas about how to control volume of sample, everything else I have prepared..

Comment: Changing volume is simply multiplication by a constant called "gain". Mixing is simply addition. In both cases you want to prevent overflow (e.g. by saturation) but that's all. So what's the real problem? You need to clarify what you're really asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i find out what was my problem.. I was shifting sample vector right, but I just made it by `"0" & sample(15 downto 1)` but it was signed, so I had to copy MSB instead of adding just plain "0".. so answer is

```
sample(15) & sample(15 downto 1)
```

this make sample half of the original volume.. its like `sample * 0,5`